# how to run ansible command usin shell_exec() function in php

Tags: php, linux, ansible

my ansible command won't run using shell_exec function in php but the other
commands like ls, pwd works just fine note that my php code is hosted on nginx web server
and i am logged in as a 'user' in both machines my local machine and my remote server which has this name 'dockerengine'

```
<%php
shell_exec("ansible dockerengine -m shell -a 'echo hello > /home/user/hello.txt'")
%>
```

when i execute the command ansible dockerengine ... (dockerengine is my remote server) in terminal it works perfectly

note also i configured ssh keys and sudoers file on my remote server to escalate privileges auto

```
//this code contained in a file with root priv hosted on nginx

<%php shell_exec("ansible dockerengine -m shell -a 'echo hello > /home/user/hello.txt'") %>
```

---

```
// this line is written in the sudoers file of my remote server (dockerengine)

user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

---

```
// this line is written in the /etc/ansible/hosts file in my local machine
[docker]
dockerengine ansible_user=user
```

---

Comment: I appreciate that this may just be for this post but in your example you have used the percent symbol <%php as opposed to a question mark <?php to open and close your php tags.

Comment: ah ! sorry just typing mistake

Comment: if you run `<?php
shell_exec('echo hello > /home/user/hello.txt')` does anything appear in text file?

Comment: yes the local commands work perfectly

Comment: Specify the full path to `ansible`.

Comment: /usr/bin/ansible

Comment: it does not work even i specify the full path